# cisco router, error NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: cisco

I have a cisco router RV215W less than one year old, and I do:

```
$ wget https://192.168.2.254/
--2017-03-02 10:26:52--  https://192.168.2.254/
Connecting to 192.168.2.254:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify 192.168.2.254's certificate, issued by ‘serialNumber=PID:RV215W-E SN:CCQ20150HG1,CN=10:BB:18:AB:71:21,OU=Cisco Small Business,O=Cisco Systems\\, Inc.’:
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
    ERROR: certificate common name ‘10:BB:18:AB:71:21’ doesn't match requested host name ‘192.168.2.254’.
To connect to 192.168.2.254 insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

I didn't have this before. I cannot tell the IOS version right now since I don't have access to the router interface (unless I log using HTTP and not HTTPS)

If I log from the browser, I get

NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Comment: I don't see any question in your post. What is it that you would like to know?

Comment: I want to know how I can correct this error

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your post/question.

Try `wget --no-check-certificate https://192.168.2.254/`

wget tries to check the shown cert, which is obviously self-signed.